# Problems with using identical() in dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, types, dplyr, vectorization

I'd like to use `identical()` inside `mutate()` and I'm getting "strange" results. Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Consider the following example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = c(1, 2, 10, NA))
```

I'd like to check if `y` differs from `x`:

```
mutate(dat, diff = x != y)
# x  y  diff
# 1 1  1 FALSE
# 2 2  2 FALSE
# 3 3 10  TRUE
# 4 4 NA    NA
```

Has "problems" with NA, so I turned to identical:

```
mutate(dat, diff = !identical(x, y))
# x  y diff
# 1 1  1 TRUE
# 2 2  2 TRUE
# 3 3 10 TRUE
# 4 4 NA TRUE
```

Hm, that's kinda strange >> investigated and found out it had to do with diverging data types:

```
class(dat$x)
# [1] "integer"
class(dat$y)
# [1] "numeric"
```

So let's take care of aligning that:

```
dat$x <- as.numeric(dat$x)
dat$y <- as.numeric(dat$y)
```

Now, I would intuitively think that mutate would give me the same result as this:

```
sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(ii) {
  !identical(dat[ii, "x"], dat[ii, "y"])
})
# [1]  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

But it still gives me this:

```
mutate(dat, diff = !identical(x, y))
# x  y diff
# 1 1  1 TRUE
# 2 2  2 TRUE
# 3 3 10 TRUE
# 4 4 NA TRUE
```

while I'd expect this

```
# x  y diff
# 1 1  1 FALSE
# 2 2  2 FALSE
# 3 3 10 TRUE
# 4 4 NA TRUE
```

What's the reason for this and/or how would I work around this so I could still use `mutate` (which I really like)?

---

### Update

Wow, what a difference in speed!

```
identicalVectorized <- function(x, y) {
  (x != y | (is.na(x) | is.na(y))) & !(is.na(x) & is.na(y))
}

identicalVectorized2 <- function(x, y) {
  sapply(1:length(x), function(ii) {
    !identical(x[ii], y[ii])
  })
}

dat <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(c(1:4,NA, NA)), 
    y = as.numeric(c(1, 2, 10, NA, 15, NA)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mutate(dat, diff = identicalVectorized(x, y)),
  mutate(dat, diff = identicalVectorized2(x, y))
)
```

Result

```
Unit: microseconds
                                           expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
  mutate(dat, diff = identicalVectorized(x, y)) 31.672 34.164 38.79999 35.777 37.6825 120.526   100
 mutate(dat, diff = identicalVectorized2(x, y)) 58.064 60.703 66.66150 62.462 72.7260 117.593   100
```

Comment: Whats the third column in the df? you have X and Y and diff. what about the third?

Comment: First column is rownumber

Comment: `identical` is not a vectorized/elementwise function. Not sure what you're after here. And what do you mean about "problems" with NA -- that's the "right" result just from `x != y`

Comment: @Frank: right, that's the reason. `mutate` recycles the output of `identical` which is a scalar, not a vector. If you know it: fine. But IMO pretty easy to miss this >> would be great if `mutate` would throw a warning if things are being recycled in a similar way as when calling `1:3 + 1:5` (Warning message: In 1:3 + 1:5:  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length)

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer: not quite (consider the result for `dat <- data.frame(x = c(1:4,NA, NA), y = c(1, 2, 10, NA, 15, NA))`), but nice idea! And kudos for your username ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you could file an issue on github asking them to warn on recycle. I think they might be receptive (but what do I know).

Comment: Yeah, I did but Hadley prefers not to as there are numerous cases where a warning would in turn be misleading (e.g. `mutate(df, n = n(), mean = mean(x))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be your best bet:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1:4,NA), y = c(1, 2, 10, NA, 15))
mutate(dat, diff = x != y | is.na(x) | is.na(y))
```

If you want NA==NA to be TRUE (it isn't in R) use this:

```
mutate(dat, diff = (x != y | (is.na(x) | is.na(y))) & !(is.na(x) & is.na(y)))
```

---

edit:
If you want to invert the True/Falseness you can do either:

- Wrap the whole thing in parathesis and put a ! in front so:

  `mutate(dat, diff = !((x != y | (is.na(x) | is.na(y))) & !(is.na(x) & is.na(y))))`
- Or you could rethink the logic so:
  `mutate(dat, diff = (x == y & !(is.na(x) & !is.na(y)) & !(!is.na(x) & is.na(y)) | (is.na(x) & is.na(y))))`

Comment: After benchmarking it: really nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: Wow... vectorized logic really doesn't seem to be my strong suit. Out of pure interest: could you tell me how to reverse the logic to `==` instead of `!=`? I know I can simply invert your `!=`-based solution as follows: `!(x != y | (is.na(x) | is.na(y))) & !(is.na(x) & is.na(y))` but I'm failing to come up with a "purely" `==`-based logic ;-)